# Getting data from audio using HTML5

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I need to read signal from microphone output using HTML5 : [Signal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0IhV.png).
What I know is that this signal is transmitted in 9 byte packets:

- 1: command byte as ASCII character ('I','A','S','L','R','C' or ' ')
- 2-6: time in ASCII chars (2:34:56)
- 7: checksum (64 + sum of time digits)
- 8: CR (carriage return, ASCII code 0x0D)
- 9: LF (line feed, ASCII code 0x0A)

I've tried using AnalyserNode functions getByteFrequencyData() or getByteTimeDomainData() and got *some* data but it didn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a script processor, because you will need to process every sample in order not to miss any data.  Analyzer nodes take snippets of data, but will miss some.  Just examine the input data in an onaudioprocess.

Comment: I've tried doing what you suggested, I'm checking AudioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer. What I get is an array of some float values, which still does not makes sense to me. What am I missing?